# Symfony 2 firewalls - front end and admin panel with the same user

Tags: php, security, symfony

I am doing a simple CMS for a client and I am running into a firewall problem with Symfony 2 implementation of the security. I have setup 2 bundles - CMSBundle and AdminPanelBundle - the first for the front-end and the second for the admin panel. I have implemented security for the users through customer provider (implementing UserProviderInterface) via db connection to a table users with the roles ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN in a column.

Each of the logins in the bundles work fine separately via /login and /admin/login but what I am trying to do is have them working together so if the user has ROLE_ADMIN they can see the front end and the admin panel, if ROLE_USER only the front end. So if logged in on either bundle the user if having the right role would see the right stuff. My security config is as follow:

```
security:
firewalls:
    user_login:
        pattern:    /login$
        security: false
    user_area:
        pattern:    /
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key:      "user_secret"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /account/
            domain:   ~
    admin_login:
        pattern:    /admin/login$
        security: false
    admin_area:
        pattern:    /admin/
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /admin/
        remember_me:
            key:      "admin_secret"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /admin/
            domain:   ~
access_control:
    - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /account/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: /admin/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

When I login in /login, it works fine but it gives me Access Denied for /account/ for the front-end. The /admin/account works fine in the Admin Panel. I am also trying to have the /account/ completely secured while the rest of the site to be available but if the user is logged in their info should be seen via the "app.user" key in the Twig template. I tried to make only /account/ firewalled but then I lose the security context for the rest of the site. It seems like it is a easy scenario but unfortunately it doesn't work. Has anyone tried implementing something like this to point me on what I am doing wrong?

I tried also the following:

```
security:
firewalls:
    user_area:
        pattern:    /
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key:      "user_secret"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /account/
            domain:   ~
    admin_area:
        pattern:    /admin/
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /admin/
        remember_me:
            key:      "admin_secret"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /admin/
            domain:   ~
access_control:
    - { path: /account/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: /admin/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Still doesn't not work. I need two different points for the login because the administrator would login from /admin/login (with one design) and the users through the front-end /login with the front-end design. Now with this setup /account gives me Access Denied and when I try to access /admin without being logged in it takes me to /login, not /admin/login which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your intentions but...

I think you can set firewalls `pattern` to just `/` and use `access_control` at the button of `security.yml` to set fine-grain permissions:

```
access_control:
- { path: /account/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: /admin/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: /, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

From official docs:

> For each incoming request, Symfony2 checks each access_control entry to find one that matches the current request. As soon as it finds a matching access_control entry, **it stops - only the first matching access_control is used to enforce access.**

So, this will protect your `/account` and `/admin` URLs. On the other hand, `/login` and everything else will be available to every visitor (authenticated or not, does not matter).

Hope this helps...

### EDIT:

I forgot to mention: You will need to have only single firewall (with `/` pattern) or this solution will not work.

Comment: I tried to post it as a comment but couldn't fit it in. I added the change you advised but it didn't work again. I have posted the new security config in the original post.